# Can we get the firebase analytics data for past dates

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I know that we can link the Firebase analytics to BigQuery to run our own custom analytics on the current data. But what about historical data. Is there any way to get the historical event data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data from Firebase to Big Query is not retroactive. The point in time since the [linkage](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512) was established would only be available in Big Query.

Historical data before that would be available in Firebase Console for analysis.

Comment: Is this still a thing? I read online about a "backfill" functionality
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/working-with-transfers#set_up_a_backfill
but i can't find a *Transfer* for my table to edit