# Extracting historical data out of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, firebase-analytics

Any ideas how I get historical data out of Google Analytics?

My problem here is I didn't realise the Firebase / Analytics export to BigQuery wasn't retrospective for history, so I only have data from when I turned on the integration and I need everything from when the Firebase App was launched. The main data I need is events with their parameters.

I have tried a few things:

1. Connect PowerBI to Google Analytics. I can authenticate and it only
   shows "Default Account for Firebase" with no children - it doesn't
   show the apps underneath that account.
2. https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ has the same
   problem (not showing child properties).
3. I can load the
   properties and therefore analytics dataset using Google Data Studio,
   but this does not have the functionality I require that is in Power
   BI. I also couldn't locate the event parameters which I need either.

Any ideas on how to export the data?

Comment: Data is only streamed from Firebase to BigQuery when the integration is enabled. There is no way to get data from before the integration was enabled, nor after you disable the integration again. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47504655, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44364830, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62632873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Google Analytics Data API to export report programmatically: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1

However the data are not raw like with BigQuery Export. So if you want raw data there are no solution for the historical data.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - you appear right, through all my investigation I believe that there's no option to get it out. I find it absolutely unbelievable that Google doesn't offer an option for historical data.

Comment: @MichelePisani The [BigQuery Export schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846?hl=en) tracks fewer raw data points than the [GA4 Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema) does...